# File Drag Drop vs Mouse Drag

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Is there a way to programmatically monitor and differentiate between normal mouse drag with downpressed ( like normal highlighted reading ) and when file is being dragged ( like upload to browser ).

Below code helps me to get when mouse is being dragged but how can we make further differentiation

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener

def on_move(x, y):
    print('Pointer moved to {0}'.format(
        (x, y)))

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print('{0} at {1}'.format(
        'Pressed' if pressed else 'Released',
        (x, y)))
    if not pressed:
        # Stop listener
        return False

def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    print('Scrolled {0}'.format(
        (x, y)))

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_move=on_move,
        on_click=on_click,
        on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
    listener.join()
```